# Print short numbers from RandomAccessFile in Java

Tags: java

I have a task to print from RandomAccessFile (which consists of shorts represented in binary format) the number in 1st position and the number in 5th position. My file looks like this:

```
0011
1100
0001
1000
1110
1010
0101
1111
```

And the code:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("data.txt", "r");
    try {
        int size = (int)file.length() / 2;
        short[] arr = new short[size];
        int pos = 0;
        file.seek(pos); 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = file.readShort();
            pos += 2;
            file.seek(pos);
        }
        System.out.println(arr[0] + " " + arr[4]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For answer i got "12336 12336". Where is the problem. I am not familiar with the streams and started stuying them recently.

Comment: Your file is in ascii, but you're trying to read it like it was binary.

Comment: what do you mean? I need to parse every value to short?

Comment: Can I use smth like this : `arr[i] = Short.parseShort(file.readLine(), 2);` assuming that file is my randomaccessfile and arr is short array

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Expected output is the number which is at 1st position but converted to decimal and numbers at 5th position also converted to decimal

Answer (score 2):

You say your file looks like:

```
0011
1100
0001
1000
1110
1010
0101
1111
```

Is this a text representation you get when viewing the file, for example, with `Notepad`? Or are you viewing it with a `Binary-Editor`? So, in short, are you talking about `text` or `bytes`?

It seems to me that the file looks like this in a text editor. If that is the case then this are not actual `bytes`. A text file is always encoded with an encoding, common encodings are `UTF-8` or `ASCII`. It is likely that your text is encoded with `ASCII`. In `ASCII` the text `0` is represented by the bytes:

```
0011 0000
```

So a line of text like `0011\r\n` encoded with `ASCII`, when viewing the `raw bytes` is actually:

```
00110000 00110000 00110001 00110001 00001101 00001100
```

The `\r\n` are invisible symbols that mean `newline` (carriage return, newline). There are many `ASCII` tables available, for example [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

So, when you now read the file and use `readShort`, then you will actually read the bytes of the file and interpret them as `short`, which is a **16-bit number**.
The first 16 bits are:

```
00110000 00110000
```

If we interpret this as `short` it will be the number: `12336`. You can try it with:

```
System.out.println(0b0011000000110000);
```

The `0b` means `interpret the following byte code as number`.

Okay, that is the **source of the problem**. The solution is, do not interpret the text as bytes but rather as text actually.
Text consists of several `char`s. Thus you can use the `readChar` method instead of `readShort`. You can also just use the `readLine` method to read the whole line.

If you use the `readChar` method you will get a `char` with content `0`. You can now parse this as `short` by using `Short.valueOf(...)`:

```
arr[i] = Short.valueOf(file.readChar());
```

However there is a small problem left. At some time, when coming to the line end, you will read the `\r\n` in the file and also insert its `short-representation` into the array. You can fix this by skipping this exact value or by using `readLine` and then split the line by its characters:

```
String line = file.readLine();
for (char character : line.toCharArray()) {
    arr[i] = Short.valueOf(character);
    i++;
}
```

However with this approach your `i` is incorrect as you would then skip `\r\n` but it is not skipped in the computation of `size`. However for solving your problem there is no need for the `i`. You could just use a `LinkedList` or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinformed about your task. Seek clarification. If this file really was binary these would be not shorts but 4-bit nibbles, with the values 3, 12, 1, 8, 14, 10, 5, 15, and there would be no line breaks. But I agree with @ElliotFrisch that this is ASCII-formatted binary, not binary, in which case they are still not shorts but 4-bit nibbles. Or possibly they are hex shorts with only 0 and 1 digits present. Either way you need clarification.

NB:

1. You don't have a `RandomAccessFile`. You have a file. `RandomAccessFile` is a *class,* and only one of several possible ways of reading the file.
2. Your `seek()` calls seek to exactly where you already are, in every case. You don't need to seek when reading a file sequentially.

Comment: Oops! I made a mistake. Occasionally my teacher told me that the file is not with ".txt" extension. The correct extension is ".dat"

Comment: That tells us nothing without you telling us properly what is *in* the file. You can call it anything you like, but if it's a binary file why the line breaks? And why only four digits per value? Clarification still needed.